# page is not getting intended when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

So basically when I will click the register button it should direct me to the next page that is the three_section page.I too wrote the code for this also I have actually added validations to the page,But the button is getting clicked but it is not taking me next page.I mean next page is not getting opened.There is no error in the logcat section coming .It means my code is running ..But the page is not getting intended i.e. there is somewhere some bug.I tried solving but I am mot gettting it.

this is my new_user_register.java code

```
public class new_user_register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name1;
    EditText email1;
    EditText usname1;
    EditText password1;
    Button register;
    ToastManager toastManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_user_register);


        name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1);
        email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email1);
        usname1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usname1);
        password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String NAME = name1.getText().toString().trim();
                String EMAIL = email1.getText().toString().trim();
                String username = usname1.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = password1.getText().toString().trim();


                String emailPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]{3,32}+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,32}+$";


                boolean isAtLeastOneFieldNotEmpty = !NAME.isEmpty()
                        || !EMAIL.isEmpty()
                        || !username.isEmpty()
                        || !password.isEmpty();

                toastManager = new ToastManager(new_user_register.this);

                // You have 5 registration fields that users must fill up.
                final int totalRegistrationField = 5;

                // This will increase by 1 when a field is valid
                int validRegistrationFieldCount = 0;

                if (isAtLeastOneFieldNotEmpty) {
                    // NAME VALIDATION
                    if (NAME.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER NAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((NAME.length() > 3) && (NAME.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("NAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 3-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!NAME.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ONLY ALPHABETS ALLOWED", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                    }

                    // EMAIL VALIDATION
                    if (EMAIL.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER EMAIL-ID", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!(EMAIL.matches(emailPattern))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("INVALID EMAIL", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                    }


                    // USERNAME VALIDATION
                    if (username.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER USERNAME", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((username.length() > 6) && (username.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("USERNAME IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                    }

                    // PASSWORD VALIDATION
                    if (password.isEmpty()) {
                        toastManager.addToast("ENTER PASSWORD", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else if (!((password.length() > 6) && (password.length() < 15))) {
                        toastManager.addToast("PASSWORD IS TOO SHORT.IT MUST BE BETWEEN 6-15 CHARACTERS.", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    } else {
                        ++validRegistrationFieldCount;
                    }
                } else {
                    toastManager.addToast("ALL FIELDS ARE COMPULSORY", ToastManager.Duration.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

                if (validRegistrationFieldCount != totalRegistrationField) {
                    // Finally show all toast all screen
                    toastManager.show();
                } else {

                    // All registration fields are valid, then go to another screen.
                    Intent p = new Intent(new_user_register.this, three_sections.class);
                    startActivity(p);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my new_user_register.xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".loginpage"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">
    
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="216dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="561dp"
            android:text="NEW USER REGISTRATION"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:typeface="sans" />
    
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="168dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="207dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="277dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
            android:text="USERNAME"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="256dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="501dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/username_foreground"
            android:text="NAME"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/name1"
            android:layout_width="291dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="434dp"
            android:hint="ENTER NAME" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="144dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="229dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="386dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
            android:text="EMAIL ID"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_width="289dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="87dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="326dp"
            android:hint="ENTER EMAIL ID" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/usname1"
            android:layout_width="292dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="85dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
            android:hint="ENTER USERNAME" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t3"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="184dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_foreground"
            android:text="PASSWORD"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_width="286dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="113dp"
            android:hint="ENTER PASSWORD" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="525dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imaagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="408dp"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="292dp"
            android:src="@drawable/iimagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imagee" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imageee" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="210dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="REGISTER"
            android:textColor="@color/Purple"
            android:textSize="25dp" />
    
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my three_section xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".three_sections">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="429dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/Purple" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="472dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text="     BEGINNERS CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="238dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/DeepPink" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-27dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:text="     ADVANCED CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@color/DarkBlue" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="315dp"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:text=" INTERMEDIATE CALLIGRAPHY"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the program is entering the last "else" block?

Comment: yes.....actually it should redirect me to next page but the page is not getting intended

Comment: Provide three_sections activity code.

Comment: yes .....wait I will add xml code or java code ??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is never go inside the intent block since your **totalRegistrationField** and **validRegistrationFieldCount** never match.

You've assigned value 5 to `**totalRegistrationField**, and you just increment the **validRegistrationFieldCount** 4 times.

All what you just need is change **totalRegistrationField** value to 4.

`final int totalRegistrationField = 4;`